# Group Similar column and perform date logic on other column

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

I am trying to write a linq statement for the below logic .Please suggest .

**ID    Name    State   StartDate  EndDate**

1     Adam    NY        1/1/2010  12/31/2010

2     Adam    NY        1/1/2011  12/31/2012

3     Adam    CA        1/1/2010  12/31/2010

4     Adam    CA        1/1/2010  12/31/2010

5     Anni    NJ        1/1/2012  12/31/2012

6     Anni    NJ        1/1/2013  12/31/2013

7     Anni    NJ        1/1/2014  12/31/2014

My Output

**ID    Name    State   StartDate  EndDate**

10   Adam         NY    1/1/2010    12/31/2012

11   Adam       CA      1/1/2010    12/31/2010

12   Anni       NJ      1/1/2012    12/31/2014

the logic is when i group by name and state if the dates are same ignore the duplicate, if they are continuous then merge them , if they are disconnected dates dont merge or ignore.

Thanks

Comment: In addition to @GrantWinney's question: Are the entries always sequential? Or is it possible that someone 'skipped' a year?

Comment: @Flatter - the dates are not sequential they are random.